# Why would a species take until ~50 years to 'mature' and stop being teenagers?

Tags: science-based, biology, psychology, knowledge

I'm writing fiction in a shared world that I have some control over, and for my own benefit I'm trying to figure out a reason why the Dwarves in this world wouldn't be 'mature' until they'd reached 50.

In this world, the absolute maximum age of a dwarf is ~350. I'm going to say they mature at the same rate as humans do until they hit the early/preteens then everything slows down until around 50 years of age then progresses into full maturity around ~100 perhaps.

I can't change the ~50 cut-off/transition into adulthood, but I can try to make sense of it.

I know for humans [adolescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolescence) is a period of change both physically and psychological change, and various evolutionary and environmental pressures act to balance when it starts and ends.

However, I'm mainly considering things like going through a [reckless/rebellious phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teenage_rebellion) as the focus of what I want to understand, and why that mental rewiring would last so much longer than in humans?

For the purposes of this question Dwarves in this world have average heights between 3'5" and 4'11, but outliers exist on either end. They're also significantly heavier than the equivalent human of the same height would be.

Comment: This is a good answer to the opposite question : https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/18868/2169

Comment: Upon further consideration, I think the question really is: why do they live to the age of 350? Because the answer to that is probably the answer to this question, too.

Comment: @Ottie that's a great question I don't have an answer too. For now, is it sufficient to say *magic*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Cooperativity.**

Pre-reproductive age children are historically super useful for a family.  Chiefly and very importantly, prereproductive age humans can watch their younger siblings, who have a penchant for being eaten by leopards and falling into holes.  Mothers can concentrate on babies.  Fathers can do what they do.  Some birds use prereproductive aged children in a similar way - the sibling from the prior year sticks around to help care for the new babies.

Once your kids are grown they go to work on their own babies and are less help.

So too the dwarves.  Having a prolonged nonreproductive phase helped improve the fitness of those carrying that gene.  Perhaps in evolutionary ages past dwarves had high child mortality rates, and the presence of nonreproductive siblings reduced that mortality rate.

Comment: Great answer, I can use that

Comment: Downvoted because why would you stop them falling into holes? For a dwarf  "falling into holes" is a respected profession with a decent paycheck.

Comment: @Daron:  that was culturally insensitive of me.  I am working on that.

Comment: @Willk No one is perfect. I hope you can remember this the next time someone from a different culture makes a snide comment about the human jobs  "Professional Bed Wetter" or "Getting Hit in the Head."

Answer (score 9):

### Pre-puberty neoteny

Lots of animals have stretched their juvenile phase, including many insects, humans, and most importantly, axolotls. The reasons vary, but include:

- Environmental pressures. This applies especially if maturation is linked with a marked change in living conditions, like sprouting wings or going from gills to lungs. So, for example, your dwarves may develop very large and luscious beards at maturity, but these get caught in cogs, so un-bearded individuals may have advantages that favour a delay of the onset of puberty<sup>[1]</sup>. Or maybe it's a neurological change with behavioural effects - adult dwarves become very set in their ways, and individuals who can retain their youthful creativity for longer are at an advantage as times become increasingly industrialised.
- Sexual selection. This is often touted as the explanation for human neoteny, which has pretty disturbing implications about our hominid ancestors if you ask me. However this doesn't work if you want to keep your characters pre-pubescent - this type of neoteny is usually linked with progenesis (reaching sexual maturity whilst retaining a juvenile look).
- Nutritional limitations. Some animals delay puberty until certain nutrients are available, or until the warm season. Maybe the hormone that triggers puberty requires exposure to the sun, like vitamin D. Since the dwarves' ancestors elected to live underground, it now takes many years to bioaccumulate a sufficient amount to kickstart puberty. Or you can flip it if you prefer your characters to have adventures on the surface: deep dwarves mature much faster, and choosing to live on the surface as a "permanent teenager" is seen is a sign of irresponsibility and weak character, cutting you off from the higher strata of dwarf society.

---

[1] No *of course* they can't shave them.

Answer (score 4):

**High adult fertility/reproduction rate**

In mammals (and many other vertebrates) there is a strong evolutionary pressure to reach sexual maturity at a younger age and start reproducing - because, otherwise,  with low reproduction rates, the species may not have a chance.

This process works differently in insects. They may spend most of their lives in larva stage, reaching adulthood late in their lifetimes. Why? Because they can afford it - reproduction rates in adults can more than compensate the numbers of larvae that are lost.

Comment: Oooh that's interesting. I'm trying to think of a train for them to have a high reproductive rate in the first place though... 

Comment: While I agree with the answer, I wouldn't go the insects way: the fertility rate of bugs will alter the world the OP is creating in a major way; adult dwarves having thousands of children per couple? I would rather go with low infant mortality. If nearly no children die before adulthood, you also eliminate the pressure to grow up fast and start reproducing early. Dwarf children have no predators (just like human, so we have this long infancy compared to other mammals) and are very much inmune to diseases, so no pressure to start mating early.

Comment: I wanted to write the same thing with the addition that the dwarves ancestors multiplied to fast that food always ran out and they started to kill each other. Populations of dwarves that reached adulthood later reduced this and more of their descendants survied, so , so there was a stromg evolutionary pressure for later adulthood.

Comment: @Rekesoft that would make a good separate answer! But won't long teenage years put other pressures on society? Is there a pressure to mate later?

Comment: @Fels I also like the idea, but from evolutionary perspective, anything that happens after you successfully procreate doesn't matter. Every life being tries to get as much offspring as they can, and as long as they survive enough to reproduce themselves, dying in wars against other adults for the scarce resources available does not add any evolutionary pressure at all. Also, you have the arms disarment problem: while a world without weapons/excessive reproduction is safer for everyone, the first one taking this path risks being annihilated by the others.

Comment: Reproductive success is not determined simply by the number of offspring. To pass on your genes effectively, you need to give your progeny a good start in life so that they will also reproduce successfully. For slowly procreating species like mammals, that requires caring for your young until adulthood, and for some species, even helping out in the care of your grandchildren. Invertebrates have a different strategy, investing in offspring quantity over quality.

Comment: @Rekesoft yes, "boxed daughters/sons" is another way to get the late puberty, although this has to be at work for some time to create evolutionary shirt.

Answer (score 0):

**Beard Castration**

Beards play a huge biological role for Dwarfs. The beard is where the chemicals to transition from pre-teen to adult are created.

Shaving a dwarf is like castrating a human. It inhibits growth in one direction. Only it is less painful and more reversible than chopping off the gonads. This fact is not common knowledge among dwarfs because. . .

Beards play a huge cultural role too. A dwarf with a beard is one who has finished their First Craftsmanship Examination. If your blacksmith, mason, or carpenter has a bushy beard you can be sure his/her/their goods are approved for quality by the Central Guild.

If your blacksmith, mason, or carpenter is clean shaven, they are still an apprentice, and could get in trouble for selling their wares.

Now a human apprentice might graduate in five years. But dwarfs are such sticklers for precision, it usually takes 50 years for the apprentice to graduate. Then they are allowed to grow a beard and allowed to mature.

**On "Rebellious Teenagers":** If you are worried 50 years of rebellion is too much, then I suggest your rebellious dwarf teenagers are not so rebellious at all. In fact that are exactly as rebellious as normal human adults. The only seem rebellious compared to adult dwarfs who follow procedure and tradition to the extent of having no discernible soul.

Answer (score -1):

We live in a culture that has expectations of what maturity is and what it means and which privileges are granted with it.

These expectations have little to do with biological reality. However, they interfere with your ability to design a species where these things are important elements of the story.

Strictly speaking, there is no such thing as "teenager-dom". Puberty occurs, and a human is functionally an adult. If this is the sort of detail you are concerned with, we know quite a bit about it. Larger animals tend to take longer to become adults, smaller ones tend towards less time. Animals which are in great danger from their environment will become physically capable early... dolphins swim immediately or they can drown, antelopes walk and run within minutes due to predation. K and r strategy also plays quite a bit into it.

If instead you are concerned with, for instance, why we see many 40 and 50 yr olds today who behave irresponsibly, who are unable to care for themselves despite no obvious deficiencies, and so forth... this is because they belong to a society that through design or accident doesn't require them to do these things. They will never "grow up". It may even be somewhat true that if a person doesn't do that by their 20s or so, they may even become incapable of it.

If instead you believe that there is this magical phase of human development where a person has achieved reproductive capability, but still has all sorts of novel growth still ahead of them, physical, neurological, emotional, and psychological... well, just import that wholesale into your story, and these dwarves can be surrogate humans for story-telling purposes.

> However, I'm mainly considering things like going through a reckless/rebellious phase

Such may actually have a true biological origin, in that species that have discovered a new geography or niche would do well if offspring are spurred to strike out on their own and make new territorial claims quickly. Humans experienced this several times in our deep past. But the biological tendency is slight, and tends to be maladaptive in the environment we find ourselves in today.

Everything else is sociological, though there are few theories I find plausible. Depending on a person's politics they might decide that there is an inherent need for progress, and that an older generation is too stodgy and ossified to embrace change. Or they might decide that youth has been corrupted, and does not share the values and principles of ancestors.

Do any of these really work for your story though? Biologically, did this species experience a prehistorical time when they had new continents and environments to conquer, so much so that the tendency towards rebellion was genetically hard-coded in their neurology?

Do the socio-political things sound good for the story you're telling?

They don't have to have a rebellious phase to make them believable, and they don't have to have one to make a proposed adolescence plausible. Do you need this for a plot point?

In other ages and places, stories about youth would have had them prone to other personality flaws. Carelessness/recklessness, foolishness, gullibility. Those (and others) might take the place of a rebellious attitude.

Comment: If I understand correctly: If you take a 12 year old child and start giving them responsibilities and teaching them so that, by the time they are 16, they are equipped to be a full member of grown-up society, and then give them independence, you will not see a "rebellious sixteen year old phase". You will just see another adult.

Comment: @Daron You can do the same with 4 yr olds, and you have a 6 yr old that's capable. Anthropology's pretty strange... videos of children that age using sharp knives, starting fires and cooking meals. No stabbings or arson or idiotic accidents. Our culture does everything ass-backwards. I love my -2 score, by the way guys, way to stay classy.